# Как запустить MultiBinding с decimal

Tags: avalonia

Вот это нормально работает если Proba и Proba1 являются string. Вроде для decimal конвертер не нужен но не срабатывает при чем если это не MultiBinding то все нормально . Что не так ?

```
    <Border.IsVisible>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static BoolConverters.Or}">
                    <Binding Path="Proba" Converter="{x:Static StringConverters.IsNotNullOrEmpty}"/>
                    <Binding Path="Proba1" Converter="{x:Static StringConverters.IsNotNullOrEmpty}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
    </Border.IsVisible>
```